# Search over multiple lines regex

Tags: splunk, splunk-query

I try to find logs via search that contains a pattern over multiple log entries. E.g.

```
time n :Post Request xyz
time n1 :requestCode --> 401
```

I tried to use regex

```
conf_file=xyz | regex "Post\sRequest\sxyz\r\n.*401"
```

I checked the regex with another editor and its working fine. However Splunk never finds a result. So my question is how can I search for that pattern over those two lines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `regex` command, like most other SPL commands, only looks at the current event.  There are ways to combine events, like with `transaction`, and then use `regex` on the combined value.

Comment: Turning the query into an transaction with startwith, endswith and maxpause was doing the job. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Events, unless you do some props.conf manipulations, are each a single line

So the issue you have is that you're trying to combine separate events (with no [apparent] commonality) into a single event

***IF*** you have a relationship between `time n` and `time n1`, then you can do some `stats` processing to combine them

But without *actual* sample data, it's going to be hard to help further :)